# Why does "Open with Code" appear twice in the context menu?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I right click a file, I see `Open with Code` twice. I know one of them is from the actual Visual Studio Code installation. When I uninstalled VSCode, I noticed the the number 1 in the screenshot below remained. Where is it that coming from and how do I get rid of it?

[image: Context menu showing Open with Code twice]

Comment: The icons are different, so I suspect they're two different versions.

Comment: @CJDennis : I only see it installed once in the `Control Panel / Add Remove Programs`

Comment: I don't know the answer, otherwise I would have posted it. I'm suggesting what you should focus on to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a lingering context menu item from a previous Visual Studio Code install.  Try the following:

1. Open your registry editor. You can find this by searching for "regedit" in the Windows search bar.
2. Navigate to `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell`
3. Look for the VSCode folder.

If you see two VSCode folders at this point, open them up and see if one is pointing to a Code.exe that no longer exists. If that's the case, simply delete the folder for the nonexistent install and your problem should be fixed.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Your answer tipped to me to look into the Add/Remove Programs in the Control Panel again. I found `Code` installed and removed it. I was looking for only programs that begin with the letter V (VS Code or Visual Studio Code etc). Thank you.